# What features in profile setting are manually migrated and which ones are automated to production

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, custom-profile

We are planning to migrate around 30 profiles to production from our development sandbox. We want to know on profile settings like tabs, custom object permission, general administrative settings etc,which profile settings are automatically migrated using a changeset and which ones need to be done manually in the production org? Can you guys send me a list on profile settings alone please?
Buyan

Comment: I thought this was pretty clearly documented here: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_perm_sets_profiles.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is the doc that explains it](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_perm_sets_profiles.htm&language=en_US)

> For custom object permissions, custom field permissions, Visualforce
>   page access, and Apex class access, you must include supporting
>   components in the change set. For example, object permissions for the
>   custom object Items are included only if the Items object is also
>   included.

There is a table in the doc that what tabs and custom object settings are sent in a changeset. I could not get it formatted properly here

Comment: Eric, can you add some of the relevant content from the doc? Generally it's good for people to be able to see the answer right away, and there's nothing to stop links breaking over time. If we have the info right here then it'll never go missing. Should it go out of date, it can always be edited!

Comment: @Eric, Could you attach the document or send me a link please?

Comment: Click on the text: Here is the doc that explains it

Comment: @Eric Thanks for the document. In the document, profile permissions like Administrative permissions, login hours, desktop integration clients are not provided. Does this mean these settings should be done manually in the destination org when we deploy?

Comment: @buyankumar Not sure and I do not have permissions in my production org to test. Best way is to test it out if you can.